# Absolute and relative imports with respect to structure of a project

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path, project-structure

I'm having a hard time understanding how imports work in Python 3.x. Suppose I have a project structure like this

```
test
../foo
....foo1.py
....foo2.py
../bar
....bar1.py
```

My understanding is that `foo` and `bar` can be treated as packages and the `.py` files as modules.

I want to import `foo1` and `bar1` in `foo2`(which is the main script). How can that be done in both absolute and relative ways?

If I want to execute `foo2` after this, is this a bad project structure (maybe `foo2` should be placed elsewhere, but I do not want to place it at the root)?

Comment: The answers to the question [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) might be helpful reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import importlib

name = input('Enter module name:')
importlib.import_module(name)
```

If you want more information on importlib, check https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib